# Where to get Chainlink VRF token for Matic?

Tags: polygon, solidity, chainlink

According to the documentation, I have to use this token to generate a random number

```
https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#polygon-matic-mainnet
```

But I don't know where to get it, I tried to buy a link token using quickswap.exchange, but these are different tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the bridged LINK token is not ERC-677 compatible, it can be converted using the PegSwap service:

https://pegswap.chain.link/